# Javascript filter out for a category

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects.

```js
const regions = [
{id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
{id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
{id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
{id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
{id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
{id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
{id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
{id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
{id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}

]

console.log("PROVINCES",regions.filter(e=> !e.region_parent_id));

// get districts
let province_ids = []
regions.forEach(e=>{
  if(!e.region_parent_id){
    province_ids.push(e.id)
  }
})

console.log("PROVINCE IDS",province_ids)

regions.forEach(e=>{
  if(province_ids.includes(e.region_parent_id)){
    console.log(e.region_name,"IS A DISTRICT")
  }
})
```

These objects can be categorized into 3 types.

1. Province
2. District
3. City

Relationship is City belongs to a District, District belongs to a Province.

I could get Provinces, districts easily like this.

Can you please tell me how can I get cities?

Comment: Create a list of district IDs, and then do the same as you did to get the districts.

Comment: Where is Province, District, City in your array ?

Comment: You seem to be missing anything related to cities in your question. Can you add that?

Comment: Nothing is missing. The entries without a parent ID are provinces, the entries where the parent ID refers to a province, are districts, and the entries where the parent ID refer to a district, are cities.

Comment: _"City belongs to a District, District belongs to a City"_  was one of these meant to be _"provinces"_?

Comment: Robby, that would be excellent information to include, now we can understand your data's structure and how cities are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```js
const regions = [
  {id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
  {id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
  {id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
  {id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
  {id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
  {id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}
];

const provinces = regions.filter(r => r.region_parent_id == null);
const districts = regions.filter(r => provinces.some(p => p.id === r.region_parent_id));
const cities = regions.filter(r => districts.some(d => d.id === r.region_parent_id));

console.log("Provinces: ", provinces);
console.log("Districts: ", districts);
console.log("Cities: ", cities);
```

Not the most efficient approach to be sure, but should not pose any problems as long as your list of regions is relatively short.

Answer (score 1):

You can start at the top level and filter the array for each sub level. Each time save a set of the ids so you can find the children by looking up their ids in the parent set in constant time:

```js
const regions = [{id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},{id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},{id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},{id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},{id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},{id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},{id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},{id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},{id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},{id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},{id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}]
    
let provinces = regions.filter(e => !e.region_parent_id)
let province_id = new Set(provinces.map(p => p.id))

let region = regions.filter(e => province_id.has(e.region_parent_id))
let region_id = new Set(region.map(r => r.id))

let cities = regions.filter(r => region_id.has(r.region_parent_id))

console.log("provinces:", provinces)
console.log("regions:", region)
console.log("cities:", cities)
```

Answer (score 1):

`console.log("CITIES",regions.filter(e=> (e.region_parent_id && regions.find(x=> x.id==e.region_parent_id).region_parent_id!=null)));`

returns

```
CITIES 
(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 5, region_name: "Nugegoda", region_parent_id: 2}
1: {id: 6, region_name: "Maharagama", region_parent_id: 2}
2: {id: 10, region_name: "theldeniya", region_parent_id: 8}
3: {id: 11, region_name: "penideniya", region_parent_id: 8}`
```

PS - there is a simple hack in your case though. Once you have filtered out the Provinces and Districts, the remaining ones in the parent array are all cities. No need for complex JS queries.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const regions = [
{id:1,region_name:"Western province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:2,region_name:"Colombo",region_parent_id:1},
{id:3,region_name:"Gampaha",region_parent_id:1},
{id:4,region_name:"Kaluthara",region_parent_id:1},
{id:5,region_name:"Nugegoda",region_parent_id:2},
{id:6,region_name:"Maharagama",region_parent_id:2},
{id:7,region_name:"Central province",region_parent_id:null},
{id:8,region_name:"Kandy",region_parent_id:7},
{id:9,region_name:"Mathale",region_parent_id:7},
{id:10,region_name:"theldeniya",region_parent_id:8},
{id:11,region_name:"penideniya",region_parent_id:8}

];

function find(obj,index=0){
  if(obj.region_parent_id){return find(regions.filter(r=>r.id==obj.region_parent_id)[0],++index);} return index;
}

regions.forEach(r=>{
 let index=find(r); 
 if(index==0){console.log(`Province ${r.region_name}`);}if(index==1){console.log(`District ${r.region_name}`);}if(index==2){console.log(`City ${r.region_name}`);}
});
```